# Set div width using D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I created a `div` in my `html`,

```
<div id="search"></div>
```

I want to set its width to 15% of my window width in my Javascript. I'm attempting to use D3 to do this:

```
var width = 0.15 * window.innerWidth,
    height = 0.95 * window.innerHeight;

var searchcolumn = d3.select("#search")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);
```

I can see in the DOM, the width and height of my div has been changed:
[image]

However, in the rendered html the `div` is just `10px x 10px`.

[image]

Why does this happen? I do not have any `CSS` that overwrites the size of the `div`. How do I set my `div` to my desired width?

Comment: Specify the unit, i.e. `width + "px"`.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old post but for anyone else wanting to solve this, the following will work :

```
var width = 0.15 * window.innerWidth,
    height = 0.95 * window.innerHeight;

var searchcolumn = d3.select("#search")
                    .style("width", width + 'px')
                    .style("height", height + 'px');
```

I have added is `+ 'px'`; and also changed `.attr` to `.style` as it's the CSS you are working with here.

Working code :

```js
var data = [10,12,6,8,15];

var svg = d3.select('body')
//.append('svg')
.attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

var width = 0.15 * window.innerWidth,
    height = 0.95 * window.innerHeight;
     
svg.selectAll('div')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('div')
  .attr('class','divs')
  .attr('x', function(d,i) { d.clicked=false; return 100+100*i; })
  .attr('y', function(d,i) { return 0; })
  .style('width', width + 'px')
  .style('height',height +'px')
  .attr('background-color', function() { return 'red'; }) 

  .text(function(d){ return d;})
```

```css
.divs { 
  background: blue;  
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:
`d3.select("#search")
       .style("height", height)
       .style("width", width);`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do the following when you want to set multiple style attributes instead of repeating `style(" ", " ")` `n` times:

```
d3.select("#search").style({
  'height': height+'px',
  'width': width+'px'
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: To whom it may concern: this comment is no longer true, due to changes in the default behavior of the library. See https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_style and  https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi